# Invalid Call on require from props url

Tags: react-native

I am attempting to set imageContent into an `<Image source={imageContent}/>` by getting content using require(props.imageUrl). Strangely (to me at least), the code works if I set image explicitly but fails on using props.imageUrl when equating them returns true.

```
export const SomeComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {

 if (props.imageUrl != null) {
    const imageUrl = '../../assets/images/profile_avatar.png'; //hardcode
    const imageUrlFromProps = props.imageUrl; //from Props
    console.log(imageUrl === imageUrlFromProps); //true
    //SectionImage = require(imageUrl); //Works
    //SectionImage = require(imageUrlFromProps); //Err: Invalid Call
  }
```

...

```
<Image source={SectionImage}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, for what I know, `require` doesn't work with dynamic value. According to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391) discussion, the reason of this problem is how `require` is loaded. Seems that `require` is loaded before runtime and if it doesn't find a resource at this time, it doesn't work .

If you really need to assign dynamic resource to `require`, what I always do is create an array of require like:

```
var resources = {
    res1: require("res1.png"),
    res2: require("res2.png"),
    ...
}
```

and then when I need to load one of these at runtime:

```
if (condition) {
   SectionImage = resources.res1;
}
else SectionImage = resources.res2;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Giovanni has suggested, require can't be dynamic. It expects static strings only (Imagine how would all static bundling would have worked if they were dynamic). The only reason I didn't vote that as the answer is because I wanted to make the component more generic. So instead of applying condition in component, I imported image from the parent component and passed into this component (which I directly set to Source).

From Parent:

```
import Avatar from '../../assets/images/profile_avatar.png'
...
<SomeComponent image={Avatar}/>
```

and in Somecomponent:

```
 let sectionImage = props.image || null;
  ...
  <Image source={sectionImage}/>
```